# JAXB and inheritance in collection

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, mapping, jaxb

how can I map (via JAXB in java 1.6) Collection to XML and from XML, where

```
class mapping{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="list")
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    Collection<A> list;
}

abstract class A{
}

class B extends A{
    public String onlyB;
}

class C extends A{
    public String onlyC;
}
```

a would like to see XML like this:

```
<something> (doesnt matter, I'm using it in another structure)
<list>
<item xsi:type="b"><onlyB>b</onlyB></item>
<item xsi:type="c"><onlyC>c</onlyC></item>
</list>
</something>
```

its working if I have

```
class mapping{        
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    A item;
}
```

I already tried xmlelementref, but with no success

and I dont want to use `@XmlElements({@XmlElement ...})` because other project which are using this can add derived class from A

Comment: When you say you trie `@XmlElementRef` without success, what exactly failes? I have used it and it works very well.

Comment: I've added `@XmlRootElement` to classes A, B, C and changed `@XmlElement` to `@XmlElementRef`, but result was only <ns:A...>

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I believe I'm hitting the same problem unmarshalling a collection here.

Answer (score 6):

Your mapping appears to be correct.  You need to ensure that the `B` and `C` classes are included when you create the JAXBContext.  One way to accomplish this is to use `@XmlSeeAlso`.

```
@XmlSeeAlso(B.class, C.class)
abstract class A{
}
```

Below is an example of using `xsi:type` to represent inheritance in the domain model with JAXB:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

`@XmlElementRef` is used when you want to represent inheritance using the XML schema concept of substitution groups:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

`XmlElements` corresponds to the choice structure in XML schema:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

---

**FULL EXAMPLE**

Below is a complete example:

***Mapping***

```
package forum7672121;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="something")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Mapping{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="list")
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    Collection<A> list;
}
```

***A***

```
package forum7672121;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({B.class, C.class})
abstract class A{
}
```

***B***

```
package forum7672121;

class B extends A{
    public String onlyB;
}
```

***C***

```
package forum7672121;

class C extends A{
    public String onlyC;
}
```

***Demo***

```
package forum7672121;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Mapping.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum7672121/input.xml");
        Mapping mapping = (Mapping) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(mapping, System.out);
    }

}
```

***input.xml/Output***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<something>
    <list>
        <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b">
            <onlyB>b</onlyB>
        </item>
        <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="c">
            <onlyC>c</onlyC>
        </item>
    </list>
</something>
```

Comment: xsitype inheratnce works for me, if I use only direct reference, but it doesn't work if objects are in collection. 
I tried `@xmlseealso` it works, but I don't know all derived classes (but they are found by JAXB because I can see them in generated XSD), so its not useful.

Comment: @PeterK - How are you creating your `JAXBContext`?  Which JAXB implementation are you using:  Metro (the RI), EclispeLink JAXB, Apache JaxMe, etc?

Comment: I must use RI which comes with Java 1.6, `JAXBContext` is created in Spring. To select root elements I'm using file jaxb.index. everything is working except this mapping (works with `@xmlseealso` but it doesn't solve my problem entirely)

Comment: @PeterK - Are you using the Oracle (Sun) implementation of Java SE 6?  If so what implementation version?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan What JAXB implementation have you successfully done this with? I seem to be hitting this using 1.7u7 w/ Metro.

Comment: @Pete - Most recently I have run this example with the JAXB impl included in JDK 1.7.0 for the Mac.  I have updated my answer to include a complete example.